# Get the row # of cell that matches with search "string" in particular column without loop - Column has multiple matches

Tags: excel, vba

Get the row # of cell that matches with search "string" in particular column without loop - Column has multiple matches"

I want to get the row # of matched string in particular column without looping because i have more than 50000 records and I don't want to loop each row to find out

```
Sub Mismatch()
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set Sht5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")

    Dim FindString As String
    FindString = "FAIL"    

    Sht5.Activate
    Columncount = Sht5.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1000)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count 'CODE NEED TO BE UPDATED WITH COLUMN LENGTH
    'To find the column count

    lastReportRow = Sht5.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    'to find the last used row

    For i = 2 To Columncount + 1
        Set Valuefound = Sht5.Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(lastReportRow, i)).Find(FindString, After:=Range("B2"), LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Valuefound Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Value not found"   
        Else
            For r = 2 To lastReportRow
                ActualString = Sht5.Cells(r, i).Value
                If FindString = ActualString Then
                    MsgBox r
                Else

                End If
                'For x = 2 To lastReportRow
            Next    
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code not Working ? what error are you getting ?

Comment: Code is working, I don't want to go each row to check the matched string to find row #. Is any way to do it.

Comment: You can print `Valuefound.Row` to get the Row number, there is no need of the Loop.

Comment: See the code below in the Answer, that should work for you.

Comment: @PrakashMahadevanSankaran what is your goal? You could use an array and a dictionary, needs looping but they are faster than any other way... Thought what is your end game? What is this for? You are just showing a MsgBox with the row if the cell is Fail?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Match:

```
    '...
    lastReportRow = Sht5.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row


    For i = 2 To Columncount + 1

        Set rng = Sht5.Range(Sht5.Cells(2, i), Sht5.Cells(lastReportRow, i))
        Do
            m = Application.Match(FindString, rng, 0)
            If IsError(m) Then Exit Do '<< not found: exit search for this column
            Debug.Print "Found '" & FindString & "' at " & rng.Cells(m).Address
            'reset search range
            Set rng = Sht5.Range(rng.Cells(m+1), Sht5.Cells(lastReportRow, i))
        Loop

     Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See in your code you can replace:

This:

```
For i = 2 To Columncount + 1


Set Valuefound = Sht5.Range(Cells(2, i), Cells(lastReportRow, 
 i)).Find(FindString, After:=Range("B2"), LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Valuefound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value not found"

    Else
      For r = 2 To lastReportRow
         ActualString = Sht5.Cells(r, i).Value
         If FindString = ActualString Then
           MsgBox r
         Else

         End If
        'For x = 2 To lastReportRow
        Next

    End If


     Next
```

---

With This:

```
Set Valuefound = sht5.UsedRange.Find(FindString, After:=Range("B2"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Valuefound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value not found"

    Else

        MsgBox Valuefound.Row

    End If
```

`Valuefound.row` will give you the exact row. Also you can add `Valuefound.column` to get the column number of the Valuefound

Also, you can add `Range.FindNext` as per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) to access the values that occur more than once in the data.

Comment: `xlWhole` vs `xlPart` just tells the the `find` method if either the **whole** string within a cell needs to match `FindString` or if only a **part** of the string within a cell needs to match `FindString`. So *"`xlWhole` take care of all the columns"* doesn't make any sense at all. • Additionall the OP said *"Column has multiple matches"* so finding all matches is impossible without a loop.

Comment: Yeah .. I was just reading about it and you are correct. Even then we should not be looping through the columns and use `Range.FindNext` instead. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext)

Comment: `Range.FindNext` will also only work with a loop. Because you will need to loop and `Range.FindNext` until there is nothing found.

Comment: Correct, But that will be much faster than looping through all the columns.

Comment: Faster than looping through each cell … probably a huge yes :) Not sure about how speed of `Find` compares to using `Match` (should be tested). • Just a note for the OP when using `Find` then the `LookAt:=` parameter **must** be set either `xlWhole` or `xlPart` otherwise it is completely random which one is used (Excel always uses what was last used by either VBA or user interface). No default if the parameter is omitted.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ .. Thanks for the information Update. Really appreciate it :)